# Is it possible/how to to set columns during update in a provider-invariant way

Tags: entity-framework-core

Would it be possible to set let's say a `DateTimeOffset Updated` property in EF7 without resorting to writing (provider-specific) SQL triggers?

I found `PropertyBuilder<DateTimeOffset>.ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` quite an interesting method but it appears the system of value generators in EF7 only supports integer columns (int, bigint, etc).

Using SQL triggers appears to be possible only by adding migrations also to contexts I use for testing which I'd like to simply be declarations only and some of those contexts use InMemoryDatabase which won't do triggers.

Comment: is it a acceptable solution ?https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `DbContext.SaveChanges()` and set the values before calling `base.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Take a look at this [NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers/)